# Compiling many txt/csv files into a single dataframe with filename added as a column

Tags: python, list, pandas, csv, glob

I'm struggling to compile many files and simultaneously add the filename as a column in the resulting dataframe.  The following script works but somehow only performs the operation on a single file... why isn't this pulling all the files together?

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os

#  format Working but only reads 1 file

indir = "C:\\location\test"
outfile = "C:\\location\test\output.csv"
#  Change the directory to where the files are located
os.chdir(indir)

#  Make an empty list
filelist = []

#  Populate list with filenames.  structure criteria with wild cards
for files in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    filelist.append(files)

print(filelist)  # so far so good, all files are in the list

#  apply a for loop to the files listed above by glob
for files in filelist:
 # built up dataframes and append the filepath as a column
    frame = [pd.read_csv(files, skiprows=21, header=None, 
delim_whitespace=True).assign(Filename=os.path.basename(files))]
    df = pd.concat(frame, ignore_index=True)
    df.columns = ['Wavelength', 'Value', 'Filename']
    df.to_csv(outfile, index=None)
    print(df)
```

I know there are a few threads already dealing with a similar matter but those threads got me to this particular brick wall somehow.

Incidentally the shape of the source files is 2256 rows by two columns (Wavelength, and Value) and I'm adding the Filename column with assign(Filename=os.path.basename()) at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are combining / confusing a `for` loop with a list comprehension. Choose one or the other, not both, for iterating `filelist`. In addition, your concatenation should occur outside your `for` loop or list comprehension.

Here, for example, you can use a list comprehension and then feed to `pd.concat`:

```
filelist = list(glob.glob('*.txt'))

frames = [pd.read_csv(fp, skiprows=21, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)\
            .assign(Filename=os.path.basename(fp)) for fp in filelist]

df = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=True)
df.columns = ['Wavelength', 'Value', 'Filename']
df.to_csv(outfile, index=None)
```